# Trigger custom AngularJS form validation on model change on other control events

Tags: validation, angularjs, customvalidator

I have created one sample date range validation directive.

When Start Date is greater then End date then we have to throw validation error. validation working properly if I change value of start date by updating value in start date text box. but validation not trigger when I change value of start date using controller event. please check below example

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="comparectrl">
     <div ng-form="testform">
     <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" ng-model="StartDate" placeholder="StartDate" />
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" ng-model="EndDate" compareto="#startdate"  compare placeholder="EndDate" />
    <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
    <br />
    <span ng-show="testform.enddate.$error.compare" >Please enter proper date.</span>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>

var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.directive("compare", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on("change", function () {
                console.log("end date on change event called");
                scope.$apply(dovalidation);
            });
            angular.element(attrs.compareto).on("change", function () {
                console.log("start date on change event called");
                scope.$apply(dovalidation);
            });
            function dovalidation() {
                var value1 = new Date(angular.element(attrs.compareto).val());
                var value2 = new Date(elem.val());
                if (value1 > value2) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("compare", false);
                }
                else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("compare", true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
app.controller("comparectrl", function ($scope)
{
    $scope.StartDate = "01/01/2012";
    $scope.EndDate = "01/01/2013";
    $scope.change = function () {
        $scope.StartDate = "01/01/2014";
        angular.element("#startdate").triggerHandler("change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Fixed it by taking a copy of the form object (testform in your code) then assigned it back after model changes. I had a `ng-repeat` inside my form. And my form model got emptied after changing the `ng-repeat` model from controller. So I kept a copy of form model and reassigned it.

```
<form name='testform'>
    <input name='fullname' ng-model='fullName'/>
</form>

$scope.change = function(){
    var copyTestForm = $scope.testform;
    $scope.fullName = 'Elon Musk';
    $scope.testform = copyTestForm;
}
```